# Permission denied opening shared library

Tags: 18.04, permissions, shared-library, selinux

I am helping a remote user who has reported an error running our software when it is trying to load one of our so files (from /usr/lib).

```
cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

The permissions should be correct but we are in the process of confirming this. However, we cannot reproduce on a local install of the same version of Ubuntu (18.04.4). Some googling suggested that SELinux could be to blame but it doesn't sound like this is enabled either.

Any other ideas for things to check would be appreciated.

Comment: My `pathlld` tool might help. https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git - Bash script to answer "Why can't I read/write that file?"

Comment: It turns out that the permissions were indeed wrong and a manual chmod has fixed it. Thanks for the script - could come in handy.

Comment: The permissions are right but I still can't access the library, not even as root…